# Отслеживание изменения содержимого каталога

Tags: c++, linux

Был бы признателен помощи с написанием такой программы:
При запуске ей передается параметром строка - директория. Далее, программа мониторит содержимое этой директории. Если в ней появляется новый файл, она вызывает другую программу, передавая ей параметром имя этого файла.
Пока есть идея с вызовом ls и сравнением с результатом предыдущего вызова, но не совсем понятно, как вычленить из то, что возвращает ls в терминал.
Кроме того, находил [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164775/) на хабре, но пример делает не совсем то, что мне нужно, а сам он слишком сложен для меня, чтобы модифицировать его.

Comment: Хм. А что вы от нас то хотите, ответом на ваш вопрос будет примерно тот же пример, что написан на хабре по inotify. Тем более по вашему "не совсем то что нужно" нельзя догадаться, что же вас не устраивает в том коде, а посему очень высока вероятность, что приведенный ответ вам так же "не совсем подойдет", а его смысл вы так же не поймете, как и тот код. И кстати  add_dir() из того примера можно выкинуть, если не требуется наблюдение за всеми директориями рекурсивно

Comment: inotifywait - готовая программа которая делает то что вы описали

Comment: Зачем писать такую программу? Используйте готовую, например https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем-то тут уже упоминали об inotify и inotifywait, но тем что действительно решило все мои проблемы оказался демон incron, основанный на inotify.

После его установки, можно настроить таблицу `incrontab -e`, в которой указывается отслеживаемая дирректория/файл, условия для выполнения действия, и сама программа/скрипт, с соответствующими параметрами на выполнение по тому условию. Причем в параметры можно передать файл, вызвавший срабатывание данного условия.

Answer (score 2):

Простое приложение inotify для отслеживания событий создания, удаления и изменения в каталоге.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )

int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
  int length, i = 0;
  int fd;
  int wd;
  char buffer[BUF_LEN];

  fd = inotify_init();

  if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror( "inotify_init" );
  }

  wd = inotify_add_watch( fd, "/home/strike", 
                         IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE );
  length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );  

  if ( length < 0 ) {
    perror( "read" );
  }  

  while ( i < length ) {
    struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
    if ( event->len ) {
      if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "The directory %s was created.\n", event->name );       
        }
        else {
          printf( "The file %s was created.\n", event->name );
        }
      }
      else if ( event->mask & IN_DELETE ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "The directory %s was deleted.\n", event->name );       
        }
        else {
          printf( "The file %s was deleted.\n", event->name );
        }
      }
      else if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "The directory %s was modified.\n", event->name );
        }
        else {
          printf( "The file %s was modified.\n", event->name );
        }
      }
    }
    i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
  }

  ( void ) inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
  ( void ) close( fd );

  exit( 0 );
}
```